# output is NaN for standard deviation - C++

Tags: c++, standard-deviation

I have a process in my client program that iterates through a custom vector, and performs some calculations to calculate standard deviation. It converts a wind speed from m/s to km/h, so its *3.6 to convert. For my sigma value, and of course my standard deviation which requires the sigma value, my output is NaN and I can't understand why this is the case.

Main.cpp:

```
float sum;
    float convertedspeed[windlog.size()];
    float sigma;
    float averagespeed;
    //float conversion;
    float sd;
    int nrofel;

    ofstream ofile("testoutput.csv");

    ofile << "WAST, S, \n";

for(int i = 0; i < windlog.size(); i++){

    nrofel = windlog.size();

    convertedspeed[i] = (windlog[i].speed*3.6);

    sum += convertedspeed[i];
    averagespeed = (sum/nrofel);

    sigma += (convertedspeed[i] - averagespeed)*(convertedspeed[i] - averagespeed);

    sd = sqrt(sigma/(nrofel - 1));
```

All my values are okay except when it gets to sigma so I expect its going wrong there. What could be the issue?

Comment: `float convertedspeed[windlog.size()];` this is most likely UB as I highly doubt that the `.size()` is a constexpr.

Comment: I'm not sure what UB and constexpr are, but windlog.size() is a method in my Vector class that simply returns the size of the vector. Note that is my own custom template class called Vector and I am not using the inbuilt std::vector. Is there something wrong with this initialization?

Comment: @thedafferg `float convertedspeed[windlog.size()];` -- This is not legal C++ if `size()` is not a constant expression.  Arrays in C++ must have their sizes denoted by a constant expression, not a runtime value.  So the first comment is more accurate than what you may have believed.  Dynamic arrays in C++ are done by using `std::vector`.  And since you have your own `Vector` class, why didn't you use it here also?  `Vector<float> convertedspeed(windlog.size());`.

Comment: You are right about me not using my own Vector class for the converted speed, I just didn't think it was necessary. And yes, it is definitely a correct approach and after reading a little bit about it I can see why, thank you. There is definitely a way to talk to people however, and as naive as I can be with learning programming know that I appreciate your comment a lot more than the first one :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must initialize variables before using.

Strictly speaking, in this case, you don't have to initialize `nrofel`, `averagespeed`, and `sd` because they are assigned some values in the loop without being read before assignment.

On the other hand, you must initialize `sum` and `sigma` because their values are read before assignment.